# Can I migrate this problem from MO to here?

Tags: support, migration

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86884) is unsolved for a long time in MathOverflow. It's a card-game-problem, so I think it's more appropriate for cstheory, but I'm not sure, so I post a meta problem here to ensure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that reposting is fine, but if you repost, please do the following:

- Link in both directions.
- Try to take care of the questions on both sites.  That is, if you receive an answer on one site, let the users of the other site know.  I understand this is not always possible, though.

You may want to include Guillaume Brunerie’s reformulation in natural language in the comment to the question on MathOverflow; it helped me understand the rules.

Comment: I'll do tomorrow. I'll try, but I think it's few probability that I will receive an answer from MO.

Comment: I've migrated, roughly mixed with GB's reformulation. You can view it.